# PHP dynamic lists of arrays

Tags: php

Please can somebody help me with a solution to make a a string list of array like:

```
$string=array1, array2, .........., arrayn.
```

I need to generate this list dynamically.
Now I send it each array in list but I want to increase the numbers and I wonder how  to put arrays dynamically inside the list.

In my code I have something like this:

```
$array[$j]
```

I need to create a list like this:

```
$string=$string.','.$array[$j]
```

...but it doesn't work. I can't send it as a multidimensional array.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: by a *list* you mean a *string*? Also, show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about a multidimensional array:

```
$container[0] = $string;
$container[1] = $array;
$container[2] = $my_other_array;
// ...
```

then for example `$container[1]` will contain your `$array` and with `$container[1][$j]` you can access the key `$j` in your original array.

Comment: I have an array like this, $array=[['arr1'=>1,'arr2'=>2], $var], I need to replace $ var with a string af arrays with same keys like first array but with different values. The $var must be generate dynamically. $var= ['arr1'=>3,'arr2'=>4],['arr1'=>4,'arr2'=>6],['arr1'=>8,'arr2'=>9]......

Comment: @butoibogdan ok, then i don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

My code is

```
 $Copii = [];
        $Config_Camere = [];
        $nrCamere = $array['Camere'];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $nrCamere; $i++) {
            if ($array['Copii_Cam' . $i] >= 1) {
                for ($j = 1; $j <= $array['Copii_Cam' . $i]; $j++) {
                    $Copii[$j] = array_combine(['AgeQualifyingCode', 'Count', 'Age'], ['c', '1', $array['varstaCopil' . $j . '_Cam' . $i]]);
                }
                if ($array['Copii_Cam' . $i] == 2) {
                    $Config_Camere['RoomRequest'] = ['IndexNumber' => $i, 'GuestsCount' => ['GuestCount' => [['AgeQualifyingCode' => 'a', 'Count' => $array['Adulti_Cam' . $i]], $Copii[1], $Copii[2]]]];
                } else if ($array['Copii_Cam' . $i] == 1) {
                    $Config_Camere['RoomRequest'] = ['IndexNumber' => $i, 'GuestsCount' => ['GuestCount' => [['AgeQualifyingCode' => 'a', 'Count' => $array['Adulti_Cam' . $i]], $Copii[1]]]];
                }
            } else {
                $Config_Camere['RoomRequest'] = ['IndexNumber' => $i, 'GuestsCount' => ['GuestCount' => ['AgeQualifyingCode' => 'a', 'Count' => $array['Adulti_Cam' . $i]]]];
            }
        }
```

And if you see i want to generate dinamicaly the array $Copii
Thanks a lot